# Perl xml - get value

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, xpath

I was using this to get the value under properties which work well when I have only one

```
$val = $child->findvalue('@value');
```

But now have several elements under properties, is there an easy way to get the value of property that is name=”BBB” ?

```
-<properties> 
       <property name="AAA" value="ABC"/> 
       <property name="BBB" value="DGT"/>
       <property name="CCC" value="DGT"/>
 </properties>
```

Comment: What module are you using? And, are you stuck with it or are you open to other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XPath.

```
$val = $child->findvalue('property[@name="BBB"]/@value');
```

For additional examples of XPaths, check out: [`XPath Examples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`findvalue` takes an XPath as an argument. The XPath to fetch the desired value with the `properties` element as the context node is

```
property[@name="BBB"]/@value
```